# React - componentDidCatch not catching errors thrown by child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I have a parent class component with `componentDidCatch` method that I would like to use for logging frontend errors to backend.

```
componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // Catch errors in any components below and log error message
    console.log(error)
    console.log(errorInfo)
    this.errorLoggGateway.loggError(`${error.toString()}, ${errorInfo.componentStack}`);
  }
```

I have also implemented my own `onUnhandledRejection` method that listens to `unhandledrejection` events:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', this.onUnhandledRejection);



onUnhandledRejection = (event) => {
    const exception = event.reason;
    console.log(event)
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') console.log('exception unhandled', exception);
    if (exception instanceof HttpError) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
        errorMessages: this.generateHttpErrorMessages(exception)
      });
      return;
    }

    if (exception instanceof TypeError && exception.message === 'Failed to fetch') {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
        errorMessages: {
          user: 'Fetch failed',
          admin: 'Problems with network or API, please contact IT-service'
        }
      });
      return;
    }

    if (exception instanceof Error && exception.name === 'AbortError') {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
        errorMessages: {
          user: 'Request timeout fail.',
          admin: `Request timeout fail, please contact IT-service`
        }
      });
      return;
    }
    this.errorLoggGateway.loggError(exception.message);
  };
```

This is the render method:

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.hasLoaded) {
      return <Loader/>;
    }
    return (
      <>
        <ExceptionDialog errorMessages={this.state.errorMessages} onDismiss={() => this.rebootApp()}/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Redirect to="/login"/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/login"
                 render={(props) => <LoginPage {...props} loginWithPromise={(fnr) => this.login(fnr)} />}
          />
          <PrivateRoute path="/exam" userToken={this.state.userToken}
                        render={(props) =>
                          <GetTime>{
                            ({currentTime}) =>
                              <ExamRootPage {...props} />
                          }
                          </GetTime>
                        }
          />
          <Route path="/preview" render={(props) => <PreviewRootPage {...props} stompGateway={this.stompGateway} />} />
          <Route component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
      </>
    );
  }
```

If I throw an error from the method in a child component, in this case **ExamRootPage**:

```
handleAnswer = (question, answer) => {
    throw new Error('Crashed');
```

I get the usual React screen with an error:

```
Error: Crashed
ExamRootPage.handleAnswer
C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/Projects/project/frontend/src/pages/ExamRootPage.js:193
  190 | };
  191 | 
  192 | handleAnswer = (question, answer) => {
> 193 |   throw new Error('Crashed');
```

Why neither the `componentDidCatch` nor the `onUnhandledRejection`  didn't catch that error?
How can I fix this so that I can handle such errors there?
I am using React version **^16.12.0**.

Comment: Error boundaries will only catch errors in the constructor, render, and lifecycle methods of children components. If `handleAnswer` is an event handler, you should guard it with try/catch blocks. https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html